# slideToggle doesn't work when Click and Panel divs are not right next to each other

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slidetoggle

I am having a problem with `slideToggle()`. I have a dynamically generated table that includes this HTML:

```
<div class="Click">Click to see more info</div>
<div class="Panel">Some information...</div>
```

The `slideToggle()` works properly when both div 'Click' and 'Panel' are right in this order and right next to each other. However, when I move div `.Click` to any other section of the document, the toggle will stop working. I am not sure if the `$(this).next()` part of the jQuery code has something to do with it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Click").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".Panel").slideToggle("fast");

    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If the elements are not next to each other then `next()` will not work. You need to use `nextAll()` or some other method of DOM traversal. You haven't shown your actual HTML sample of the element separated so can't guide you on that

Comment: If you added `id` attributes to each, you could target specific panels with specific buttons or clicks.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise, if you can, to add `id` attributes to your elements. You can also use a `data` attribute to create a relationship.

**HTML**

```
<div id="btn-1" data-rel="panel-1" class="Click">Click to see more info</div>
<div id="panel-1" class="Panel">Some information...</div>
```

In this way, the element that is clicked can be anywhere in the document.

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
  $(".Click").click(function(){
    $("#" + $(this).data("rel")).slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

This would target `#panel-1` and execute the `.slideToggle()` upon it. If you had a number of buttons and panels, you're just nesting their relation ship to each, and this would all work as long as they all have the same class.

Answer (score 0):

In your case next() selects the very next element , you can use the following instead

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Click").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings(".Panel").eq(0).slideToggle("fast");

    });
});
```

Select the siblings with .panel class and i added eq(0) that would limit the selection to the first sibling that has class panel after the div with click class.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".Click").click(function(){
   $(this).siblings(".Panel").eq(0).slideToggle("fast");

  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Click">Click to see more info</div>
<div class="next">sample</div>
<div class="next">sample</div>
<div class="Panel">Some information...panel 1</div>
<div class="Panel">Some information... panel 2</div>
```

Hope this helps ! :)